# Underscore filter array of object using like query

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the below Json.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "Some Name"
    },
    {
      "id": "124",
      "name": "My Name"
    },
    {
      "id": "125",
      "name": "Johnson Johnson"
    },
    {
      "id": "126",
      "name": "Mike and Mike"
    },
    {
      "id": "201",
      "name": "abc xyz"
    },
    {
      "id": "202",
      "name": "abc befd"
    },
    {
      "id": "210",
      "name": "jki yuiu"
    },
    {
      "id": "203",
      "name": "asdfui uiuu"
    },
    {
      "id": "204",
      "name": "sfdhu uiu"
    },
    {
      "id": "205",
      "name": "asdfui uyu"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using Underscore i want to filter the above data using sql like query on id.
for example if pass "2" the json should be filtered and return a new json which contain id starting with 2, If i pass 20 it should return new json with id starting with 20

similar to sql like query and then return **n** results matching,

correction: I want the data starting with id 2 or whatever parameter i pass i need data starting with it

Comment: `arr.filter(obj => obj.id.indexOf("2"))`

Comment: try http://underscorejs.org/#where

Comment: @Tushar is right. There's also an `_.filter` method in Lodash/Underscore. You'd know this if you'd bothered to google before you asked the question, `Array.prototype.filter` is the top result for 'filter javascript array'!

Comment: @user804401 Checkout my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function getResult(keyToFilter, valueStartsWith){
    return _.filter(results, function(d){ return d[keyToFilter].startsWith(valueStartsWith); })
}

getResult("name", "asdfui");

[{
  "id": "203",
  "name": "asdfui uiuu"
},
{
  "id": "205",
  "name": "asdfui uyu"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.slice`? (underscore has similar functions but why to use them when it can be solved with plain JS)

```
function sqlLikeFilter(data, id, maxn) {
    return data.result.filter(function(x) { return x.id == id; }).slice(0, maxn);
}

console.log(sqlLikeFilter(yourData, 125, 1));
```

Comment: correction: I want the data starting with id 2 or whatever parameter i pass i need data starting with it. I thought underscore will help

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
function(id){
    var result = _.filter(results, function(value) {
        return value.id === id
    })
    return result;
}
```